# Tableview cell play video when double clicked then it will be full screen mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avfoundation

I am trying to achieve play a video which is in the table view cell and it is working fine . Now i want  to play that video in full screen mode when double clicked . I am not sure, how to achieve that. And tried with  `UITapGestureRecognizer` when double clicked then it will be full screen mode, but I am getting the following error.

> Value of type 'AVPlayer?' has no member 'view'

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

           let videoURL = URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds

    cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

    //handle full screen mode
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
    let view = UIView(frame: cell.contentView.frame)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    //player.view.addSubview(view) // /// Value of type 'AVPlayer?' has no member 'view'


    return cell
}



 func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("tap tap")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error it self clearly telling you that

> Value of type 'AVPlayer?' has no member 'view'

Because `AVPlayer` is not subclass of `UIView`. And it does not and any property called `view`.

And the line of code `player.view.addSubview(view)` can not execute.

Comment: thanks but how can i achieved  the full screen mode video play when double clicked . i spend two days please

Comment: can you share any demo project? @cristainlika3